# Difference between <script async> and $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any major difference?

Does one allow additional functionality?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script async>` loads the script in the tags asynchronously, and $.ajax calls a server asynchronously.

The former is a way to load JavaScript without blocking other downloads. This is explained here: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/blocking-the-dom/

The latter is an XML HTTP Request and can be used to send or retrieve resources without leaving the page. E.g. sending form data or retrieving a JSON with a service call. An example of posting form data:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Straight from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Ah right, thanks for the explanation and links :)